# Django4.1.6 LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL is not working

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-settings

I would like to be taken to the page after login.

I want to login using the LoginView class, but the login page just reloads and does not take me to the page after login.

The terminal says ("POST /accouts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2467).

Is the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL not working?

Signing up also does not sign up correctly as the page just reloads.

Logout works fine.

**accounts/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views import View
from accounts.models import CustomUser
from accounts.forms import ProfileForm, SignupUserForm
from allauth.account import views
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy


class ProfileView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_data = CustomUser.objects.get(id=request.user.id)

        return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', {
            'user_data': user_data,
        })


class ProfileEditView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_data = CustomUser.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        form = ProfileForm(
            request.POST or None,
            initial = {
                'first_name': user_data.first_name,
                'last_name': user_data.last_name,
                'department': user_data.department,

            }
        ) 

        return render(request, 'accounts/profile_edit.html', {
            'form': form
        })

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            user_data = CustomUser.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
            user_data.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            user_data.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user_data.department = form.cleaned_data['department']
            user_data.save()
            return redirect('profile')
        
        return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', {
            'form': form
        })


class LoginView(views.LoginView):
    template_name = 'accounts/login.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("/")


class LogoutView(views.LogoutView):
    template_name = 'accounts/logout.html'

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            self.logout()
        return redirect('/')

class SignupView(views.SignupView):
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'
    form_class = SignupUserForm
```

**mysite/settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'app',
    'accounts',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
]

#############################

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


SITE_ID = 1

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_EMAIL = 'email'
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIl_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
```

**mysite/urls
.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app.urls')),
    path('accouts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('accouts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Can you show your urls. Is there a view for '/' only ?

Comment: It should also be `ACCOUNT_EMAL_REQUIRED`.

Comment: @ArifRasim Thank you for your comment.

I have added the urls.py code.

Comment: Well, why did you define same route name `accouts/` for both, it should also be `accounts/`.

Comment: @SunderamDubey                                             Thank you as always, teacher.

I can't create a talk room yet.

See my githab profile.
DM me if you don't mind.

Comment: Hello snb, I will see the repo tomorrow night, currently I have a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `success_url` so:

```py
class LoginView(views.LoginView):
    template_name = 'accounts/login.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("your_view_name")
```

Additionally, I'd recommend you to change view names to something like `MyLoginView` and `MyLogoutView`, don't give the same as Django inbuilt views.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

I will give it a try.

Should I add the success_url to the signup class as well?

Comment: @snb No, there's no need, I think. But firsy try to change view names.

Comment: Adding success_url still only reloads and does not move the page.

It didn't work.

class LoginView(views.LoginView):
    template_name = 'accounts/login.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("/")

Comment: @snb Did you change the view names? Then I think some problem is with allauth configarations.

Comment: @snb It might be the cache issue, try to restart server in another port as `python manage.py runserver 6000`. Also provide `LOGIN_URL`.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply.

Changing the view name did not help.

class MyLoginView(views.LoginView):
    template_name = 'accounts/login.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("/")

How do I set up the correct allauth configuration?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251601/discussion-between-sunderam-dubey-and-snb).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.

I just now followed your GitHub account.